# How do I insert multiple rows int MySQL where the values of one column are from a single list of values and the others are constant

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB 10.4. I have a list of values, i.e. `one@email.com`, `two@email.com`, and `three@email.com` (my actual list is much longer).

I would like to make an SQL insert equivalent to the following:

```
insert into my_table(email, foreign_key_id, timestamp) values
('one@email.com', 1, now()),
('two@email.com', 1, now()),
('three@email.com', 1, now());
```

While only having to write something like `select email from ('one@email.com', 'two@email.com', and 'three@email.com')` somewhere in the insert query without duplicating the constants/functions on each line. Can I do this in SQL without any temporary tables?

Comment: Transfer the list into the query as JSON array, and parse back to separate values using JSON_TABLE() function.

Comment: Very interesting suggestion @Akina. Can you write this up as an answer? I'm using MariaDB 10.4 so JSON functions are acceptable. I'm not a huge fan of the union solution, at that point, I would just make value rows.

Comment: *Can you write this up as an answer?* Done. Not applicable to MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO my_table (email)
SELECT email
FROM JSON_TABLE( @value,
                 "$[*]" COLUMNS ( email VARCHAR(32) PATH "$" 
                                ) 
               ) AS parse_JSON;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9c12e0d6315357a77801eb9ac43ad53a)

Applicable to MySQL 8+

---

For MariaDB 10.2.3+ use something close to (online fiddle issues incomprehensible errors where there are clearly no errors - so I cannot test)

```
INSERT INTO my_table (email)
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT 0 AS num, JSON_VALUE(@json, '$[0]') AS email
         UNION 
         SELECT num + 1, JSON_VALUE(@json, CONCAT('$[', num + 1, ']'))
         FROM cte
         WHERE JSON_VALUE(@json, CONCAT('$[', num + 1, ']') IS NOT NULL
       )
SELECT email
FROM cte;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select`:

```
insert into my_table(email, foreign_key_id, timestamp) values
    select e.email, 1, now())
    from (select 'one@email.com' as email union all
          select 'two@email.com' union all
          select 'three@email.com'
        ) e
```

Comment: Good answer. It's not desirable to create this statement for 1000+ values. The first half of the accepted answer looks the cleanest, but this is better than the second half of the accepted answer.